# Django - Trying to render a modelform or formset get error I don't understand: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'editable'

Tags: django, django-forms

trying to create a simple modelform
model:

```
class Category(BaseModel):
    categoryText = db.StringProperty()
    parentCat = db.IntegerProperty()
```

form:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    categoryText = forms.CharField(editable=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
```

view:

```
if request.POST:
   pass
else:
form = CategoryForm()
    return render_to_response('adminCategories.html', {'form': form})
```

I get an error :

**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'editable'

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`editable` is for model fields, not form fields. If you want a form field to be read-only then you will have to [use a different widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#specifying-widgets).